# Have any conclusions been made regarding the interaction of Covid-19 and ACE inhibitor medications?

Tags: medications, covid-19, coronavirus, ace2

About two months ago, I started to see articles appear regarding the potential interactions between ACE inhibitor medications (commonly used to treat high blood pressure) and the severity of Covid-19

The articles centered around the idea that Covid-19 attaches to the ACE2 enzymes and people taking these medication have more of them.

Various studies have been conducted questioning if it would make the people taking these medications more prone to infection, or if the infections would be more severe, etc. Some hypothesis was also made that a higher level of ACE2 could have a protective role if an infection is established.

A quick search returns many links and all of them seem to say that more research is needed. The general conclusion is that people taking these medications should continue to take them for now. Many of these papers are in pre-print, some by people that do claim receiving grants from companies manufacturing these drugs, etc.

Has a consensus been somehow reached? or are things still totally fuzzy in that domain?

Comment: I'm going to send this over to MedicalSciences.SE because I think it's a better fit for there since it's talking about medical practice rather than general epidemiology or the biology underlying medicine. In either venue, though, it would be helpful if you cited some of the inconclusive literature you've found; I don't have good hope of a less fuzzy answer than what you've seen, though. We're in the middle of an active and still quite new pandemic.

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21430 may answer your question

Comment: yes, this could be considered a duplicate. We can close my question. Thanks!